# keycloak, angular: Authorization on demand

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on, keycloak

I wonder how to implement Angular app secured by Keycloak, the way that only some resources will be secured.

eg.:

- unauthorised user access http://localhost:8000/#/**public** -> user is NOT redirect
- unauthorised user access http://localhost:8000/#/**private**  -> user is redirrect to keycloak login page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular `ngRouter` or `uiRouter` to do this. Both of these have the `resolve` function in their route/state definitions.

Every time a URL is hit, you can verify with your backend (Keycloak) using a token if the path is secure, and route the user accordingly.

You can use  interceptors to add auth tokens and such to each request like so

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

[This](https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth) is a great tutorial for Auth using Angular and JWT, and the concepts can be extended for any auth mechanism, whether it is oAuth or Keycloak